# "What's hot" / "best selling" showing deleted products

Tags: widgets, widget

I have a widget on the homepage of [www.crystelleclothing.com](http://www.crystelleclothing.com) which displays the best welling products... Problem is, it shows blank products where the best selling ones have been deleted...

Any thoughts would be great.

Answer (score 1):

A best selling widget sounds like aggregated data.
Try to refresh the flat indexes from the backend via
`system > index management > select all > reindex`

Also refresh the reports and cache in the backend to be sure you're displaying the latest data.

Comment: Clearing cache and re-indexing did nothing...

Comment: refreshed the reports and this did nothing either...

Answer (score 0):

Try reindexing your data if required and refresh all caches.